# How to return only one tweet, using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm very new to tweepy, Right now the code below only outputs results to the screen,
But what I want to do is: pass each single result to the variable:

for example:

```
tweet = Twitter().start() 
print tweet
>> justinbieber
```

So My problem is I don't know how to return one value at a time.

Right now I have this, the code below will go forever and after I press Ctrl + C it wan't store the result in tt:

```
>>> import twitter_streaming_tweepy as t
>>> tt = t.Twitter().start()
alwaysupportjus
Madam_Rauhl
```

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import tweepy

output = []

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            print status.author.screen_name
            output.append(status.author.screen_name)

        except Exception, e:
            print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
            pass

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

class Twitter():

    def __init__(self):

        consumer_key="*******"
        consumer_secret="*******"
        access_key = "*******"
        access_secret ="*******"

        self.auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        self.auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
        self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)


    def start(self):
        l = CustomStreamListener()
        stream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(self.auth,l)
        stream.filter(follow=None, track=['justinbieber'])
        return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Twitter().start()
```

Comment: You're using a `StreamListener` that's why the tweets are, well, streaming. Have a look around the API to see if there is a non-streaming tool you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Make a variable called 'tweet' in the class and use the on_status event to send the received object  to the  variable using this.tweet = status.

As a performance tip, if you process the statuses one by one, this will cause program get delayed from Twitter and Twitter cuts you off the stream. Make sure to a list or a queue to process tweets as batch in another thread.

Have Fun.